# Javascript IIFE: Immediately Invoked Function Expression execution. how it runs?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to understand how IIFE in JS works.

I first ran this:

```
(function boo() {
      var i = 90;
      console.log(i);
    })();
```

and adding below

```
boo();
```

doesn't run.

Q1: Why? is this named iife not stored for reference to be called later on?

When I do this

```
 var tee = function boo() {
  var i = 90;
  console.log(i);
};

tee();

boo();
```

it runs

but when I do this

```
 var tee = function boo() {
  var i = 90;
  console.log(i);
};

boo();

tee();
```

It doesn't run.

Q2: Why?

Comment: This has nothing to do with IIFE. Both of them are actually broken. `boo` is not defined in either of those examples. Look at the console.

Comment: @FelixKling just made an edit

Comment: @user2290820: Your second snippet (for Q1) still throws an exception, only it does this after `tee()` ran successfully.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Q1: Why? is this named iife not stored for reference to be called later on?

Basically yes. The name of a function **expression** does *not* become a symbol in the enclosing scope. E.g. if you have

```
var foo = function bar() {
  // `bar` is defined here, `foo === bar`
};
// only `foo` is defined here
```

then you can only access `foo`. `bar` is only accessibly **within** the function (and refers to the function itself). See [Named function expressions demystified](https://kangax.github.io/nfe/) for more info.

> Q2

This has nothing to do with IIFE. Both of them are actually broken.

The reason why you don't see an output in the second example is because you are trying to access `boo` (which does not exist) *before* calling `tee` (which does exist).

JavaScript stops executing the code when it throws an error, hence `tee` is never called.

Comment: So it doesn't run because there is an error. I get it. Running on chrome console , tracing this sort of runtime error is hard.

Comment: I didn't understand your first response. the func. exp. name cannot be called you mean for reuse?